# Legally including open-source library in program

Tags: java, djnativeswing

I am considering using [this library](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) in my closed-source java program. I want to distribute this program as a single JARfile. How can I include this library in my JARfile, and how can I give credit legally? I am using eclipse IDE and am willing to use the tools it comes with if I can. EDIT: I have decided not to use this library, and will create another question for the one I switched to.

Comment: The website says its license is the LGPL. I recommend researching that.

Comment: Check the license carefully.  It's listed as "GNU or LGPL".  If it's GNU, then you may _not_ include it in your closed-source program.  If it's LGPL then you can - I suggest you confirm with the author.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-java.html

Comment: @user3053430 is the library you are instead using also LGPL? If so, it might just be better to edit this question

Answer (score 1):

The library you are considering using is licensed under LGPL which means you are licensed to link against the library, but not include any source from it. I think it only reasonable to acknowledge the use of the library source in your own code, even though you are not distributing it. However you should acknowledge your usage with a 'parts of this work are copyright ...' in your own small print

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be LGPL code.For LGPL from [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License)

> The license allows developers and companies to use and integrate LGPL
>   software into their own (even proprietary) software without being
>   required by the terms of a strong copyleft license to release the
>   source code of their own software-parts. The license requires that
>   only the LGPL software-parts be modifiable by end-users via source
>   code availability. For proprietary software, LGPL-parts are usually in
>   the form of a shared library such as a DLL so that there is a clear
>   separation between the proprietary and LGPL parts. The LGPL is
>   primarily used for software libraries, although it is also used by
>   some stand-alone applications.

Comment: so how can I include this in my JARfile under these terms?

Comment: @user3053430 You _may not_ include it _into_ your jar file.  It _must_ be distributed as a separate file, with its own copyright notice.